# choose the best class if 2 class have same P (c|d), naive bayes

Tags: classification, data-mining, text-mining, bayesian

Hello I have some question about naive bayes classifier .
In my project I have to classify a text into a class from 4 available class.

In naive bayes we have formula like

```
cmap=argmax.P(d|c).P(c)
```

I have standarize the amount of training document of each class, so I got a same `P(c)` value for each class (0.25).

Here's my question: What if a testing document token doesn't have any token which belong to any of those 4 class(in document training)?

Resulted to all of the class have same value of `P(d|c).P(c)`. 
Which class should i pick?

What if the token exist, and 2 class or more have same value of `P(d|c).P(c)` what should I do?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

If the classes posteriors are the same, it should not matter.

As a tie breaker, you can prefer the class with the higher prior, i.e. the more frequent class.

But your bayesian analysis just showed that *you are guessing*.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes. from the naive bayes perspective it is true it should not matter. but in the evaluation process it's matter. I use if-else rules(like in the sorting algorithm ) to choose which class is the maximum. so my classifier always choose the first class (the first if = true). it's makes the precision from the first class decline..if you have some idea to break this tie without decrease the precision of that class i would be happy... thanks :) *sorry for my bad english*

Comment: What I was trying to say is: if they are equally likely, you can toss a coin, or prefer the larger class.

Comment: What about using the prediction of a second supplementary classifier?

Comment: Why only supplementary then? If you have another classifier, make a real **ensemble** right away. But note that the supplementary classifier / ensemble can also yield a tie.